# Let's get critical: Apr 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: The above linked Review Queue is now finished (of course).  When is the next scheduled Site Self-Evaluation Review Queue going to come out?  Sounds like an interesting endeavor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Joomla plugins are not working even when they are enabled](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/9079/joomla-plugins-are-not-working-even-when-they-are-enabled)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Limiting Values for Calendar DatePicker](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/8843/limiting-values-for-calendar-datepicker)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How checkEditId() method protect from direct edit a record](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/8820/how-checkeditid-method-protect-from-direct-edit-a-record)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Where is the menu item ID?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/9057/where-is-the-menu-item-id)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Joomla 2.5.x 403 Forbidden](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/9099/joomla-2-5-x-403-forbidden)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How to add an article to a template](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/9059/how-to-add-an-article-to-a-template)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Joomla Backend - Cannot login after switching to new host. "An error has occurred. 0 Cannot open file for writing log"](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/8835/joomla-backend-cannot-login-after-switching-to-new-host-an-error-has-occurre)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Error messages in joomla site after installing sobipro](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/8780/error-messages-in-joomla-site-after-installing-sobipro)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [How do I create a hidden menu with hidden articles?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/9065/how-do-i-create-a-hidden-menu-with-hidden-articles)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [How to prevent "Featured"appearing in the title tag of my K2 featured articles?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/8982/how-to-prevent-featuredappearing-in-the-title-tag-of-my-k2-featured-articles)

**Net Score: -8** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 8)

---